# sbt-buildinfo plugin: How can I add the java version in effect at compile time to the generated BuildInfo.scala?

Tags: scala, sbt-buildinfo

The build info plugin is working fine for me, but I am wondering if I could add to the generated `BuildInfo.scala` source file the version of the JDK with which it was generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do

```scala
buildInfoKeys += BuildInfoKey.action("javaVersion")(sys.props("java.version"))
```

The four properties you might want to capture are `"java.vm.name"`, `"java.vm.version"`, `"java.version"`, `"java.runtime.version"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `SettingKey`, like:

```
lazy val jdkVersion: SettingKey[String] = SettingKey[String]("jdkVersion", "JDK Version")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
  .settings(
    ThisBuild / jdkVersion := System.getProperty("java.version"),
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion, jdkVersion),
    buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.ToJson,
    buildInfoPackage := "myproject.version"
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't try this as 0__'s answer above is shorter, but suspect it would also work. I wish I could accept two answers.

Comment: you can still upvote it;) But you are right cool answer from @0__